# Issue in Appending to the Blobs in Python

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to the Append to the Blobs if the Blob already exist, but from the below code I can only create a file, but can't append to the existing blob.

```html
filename = x + '.csv'
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system=date_time+"9")
    file_client = file_system_client.create_file(filename)
    local_file = open(filename, 'r') # Change the Path over here !!!
    file_contents = local_file.read()
    file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))
    file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

I have tried to append using below code, but I think I am using wrong syntax from azure

```html
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test-data")
    # Get the Blob Names from the Container
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test-data")
    blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    # Check the Blob name is present or not
    for blob in blobs_list:
        if blob.name == sourceid + ".csv":
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        file_client = file_system_client.get_file_client(sourceid + ".csv")
    else:
        file_client = file_system_client.create_file(sourceid + ".csv")
    local_file = gzip.open(filename, 'r')  # Change the Path over here !!!
    file_contents = local_file.read()
    file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))
    file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved by Following code Snippet... Finally got the syntax to append the blobs which are in csv by python...

```py
flag = False
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***********;AccountKey=*************;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(
        account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format("https", "********"),
        credential="************")
    file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="test-data")
    # Get the Blob Names from the Container
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("test-data")
    blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    # Check the Blob name is present or not
    for blob in blobs_list:
        if blob.name == sourceid + ".csv":
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        file_client = file_system_client.get_file_client(sourceid + ".csv")
        file_client.get_file_properties().size
        filesize_previous = file_client.get_file_properties().size
        local_file = gzip.open(filename, 'r')  # Change the Path over here !!!
        file_contents = local_file.read()
        file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=filesize_previous, length=len(file_contents))
        file_client.flush_data(filesize_previous + len(file_contents))
    else:
        file_client = file_system_client.create_file(sourceid + ".csv")
        local_file = gzip.open(filename, 'r')  # Change the Path over here !!!
        file_contents = local_file.read()
        file_client.append_data(data=file_contents, offset=0, length=len(file_contents))
        file_client.flush_data(len(file_contents))
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an option to set the blob type as AppendBlob while uploading a blob, with help of this we can append the blobs data.

I did a repro on this scenario where the csv blob in my Azure container will have 50 contacts and my local csv file will have 100 contacts.

With the help of below code, we’ll be able to Append the data and at the end after uploading our source file will get deleted.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService, BlobServiceClient
import os

account_name = "ACCOUNT_NAME" #add your account name
account_key = "ACCOUNT_KEY" #add your account key

append_blob_service = AppendBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)

def generate_progress_callback():
    def progress_callback(current, total):
        print('({}, {})'.format(current, total))

    return progress_callback

append_blob_service.append_blob_from_path(container_name="container0805", blob_name="50-contacts.csv",
                                          file_path=r"C:\Users\saikarri\Python\100-contacts.csv",
                                          progress_callback=generate_progress_callback())

print("hello")
path = r"C:\Users\saikarri\Python\100-contacts.csv"
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
    print("delete file")
else:
    print("no such file")
```